# How do I set up RMI in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi

So I'm just starting out with RMI, and
I built this classes for server side:

```
public interface ServiceServer extends Remote
public class ServiceServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServiceServer
public interface Service extends Serializable
```

And this class for client side :

```
public class ServiceBrowser
```

When I try to run my program I get this exception:

```
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FirstTryRMI.ServiceServer
```

As I understood the problem is with the RMI not finding the classes(?).
I've looked all over and I just can't seem to understand, How do I add my class files to the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your client includes the jar files as well, it must have the ServiceServer class.

Comment: This is the next problem he will get but the current problem is that the Registry can't see that class.

Comment: I haven't done RMI in years, but I never remember having to put client jars in the rmiregistry classpath.

Comment: So where exactly is the registry going to get the remote interface and stub classes from? Look at the stack trace. He has a ServerException wrapping an UnmarshalException. So whatever server he was calling didn't have the class in its CLASSPATH. That can only be the Registry. Maybe in your case you used LocateRegistry instead of the rmiregistry command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the Registry has your remote interfaces, stubs, etc., on its CLASSPATH.